# Where exactly does Birds of Prey take place in the DC Extended Universe?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, chronology, birds-of-prey

I recently watched *Birds of Prey* and it was clear that it takes place after *Suicide Squad*, but when?

I want to know in comparison to other *DC Extended Universe* films.

Comment: Interesting but I'm not sure that SS has even established where IT fits in the DCEU chronology...has it?

Comment: @Paulie_D Suicide Squad takes place sometime between Batman vs. Superman and Justice League, since it's mentioned that Superman is dead. I'm not aware of any specific source for this, but my impression is that aside from the Wonder Woman films the DCEU movies are released in chronological order.

Comment: Considering that the upcoming 2021 movie *The Suicide Squad* is ["a new take on the property rather than a direct sequel to the 2016 film"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Suicide_Squad_(film)), is *SS* even part of any DCEU?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it definitely takes place after *Suicide Squad*, beyond that there actually is no definitive answer when it comes to the other movies in the DCEU. This is because according to the director Cathy Yan the movie takes place in an alternate timeline. When asked how long after *Suicide Squad* *Birds of Prey* takes place [in an interview with Collider](https://collider.com/birds-of-prey-movie-timeline-suicide-squad/) she said: "There is not any known amount of time. No… it kind of exists in a parallel timeline"